# How to do Code-signing using appdmg tool?

Tags: macos, code-signing, dmg

As mentioned here https://github.com/LinusU/node-appdmg to create dmg.

I did not get any example to add for "code-sign".

Has anyone used this to create dmg who can help me to know what to provide in those two placeholders? The second one being optional still I want to know.

```
{
  "title": "My App",
  "icon": "app.icns",
  "icon-size": 108,
  "background": "Resources/SplashScreen/dmg-background.png",
  "contents": [
    { "x": 450, "y": 150, "type": "link", "path": "/Applications" },
    { "x": 150, "y": 150, "type": "file", "path": "/My App.app" }
  ],
  "code-sign": [
     { "signing-identity" : ""},
     { "identifier" : ""}   
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I never used `node-appdmg`, but the documentation says:

> code-sign (object, optional) - Options for codesigning the DMG
>   signing-identity (string, required) - The identity with which to sign the resulting DMG
>
> identifier (string, optional) - Explicitly set the unique identifier string that is embedded in code signatures

You can list the code signing identities with this command:

`security find-identity -v -p codesigning`

```
1) 4E8D512C8480FAC679947D6E50190AE9BAB3E825 "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Developer Name (DUCNFCN445)"
2) 8B0EBBAE7E7230BB6AF5D69CA09B769663BC844D "Mac Developer: Developer Name (DUCNFCN445)"
3) 4E8D512C8480AAC67995D69CA09B769663BC844D "iPhone Developer: App Developer (DUCNFCN445)"
4) 65E24CDAF5B3E1E1480818CA4656210871214337 "Developer ID Application: App Developer (DUCNFCN445)"
   4 valid identities found
```

So you can specify an identity like this:

```
{ "signing-identity" : "Developer ID Application: App Developer (DUCNFCN445)"},
```

For the "identifier", you can refer to this [technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2206/_index.html). It says:

> The signing identifier is also embedded in the DR and will default to the CFBundleIdentifier found in the Info.plist for convenience if one is not supplied explicitly. The identifier has no meaning as far as code signing is concerned, other than as a means to make DRs unique.

Your .dmg won't have a bundle identifier. In my case, it seems to default this to the name of the .dmg (so, my .dmg is `myproduct.dmg`, and my default identifier comes out as `myproduct`).

After signing, you can view the signature like this:

```
codesign -dv /path/to/myproduct.dmg
```

And you will see the identifier:

> Executable=/path/to/myproduct.dmg
>
> Identifier=myproduct
>
> Format=disk image
>
> ... etc

Answer (score 1):

Wrong format, should be:

```
{
  "title": "My App",
  "icon": "app.icns",
  "icon-size": 108,
  "background": "Resources/SplashScreen/dmg-background.png",
  "contents": [
    { "x": 450, "y": 150, "type": "link", "path": "/Applications" },
    { "x": 150, "y": 150, "type": "file", "path": "/My App.app" }
  ],
  "code-sign": {
    "signing-identity" : "Developer ID Application: xxx",
    "identifier" : "<Your BundleID>"
  }
}
```